# Tkinter expand OptionMenu when focus is on it (Python 2.7)

Tags: configuration, tkinter, optionmenu

I'm trying to create a GUI with an OptionMenu that can be used with only keyboard input.

When the user tabs to the OptionMenu (and puts the focus on it), I would like it to expand to show all the different options so that the user can select an option using the Up Arrow, Down Arrow and Return. Right now I can tab to the OptionMenu, but I have to click on it to reveal the different options.

Is there a way to automatically expand an OptionMenu when focus is on it?  My current code:

```
self.status_options = ["", "Done", "In Progress"]
self.status_menu_var = StringVar(self)
self.status_menu_var.set(self.status_options[0])
self.status_menu = apply(OptionMenu, (self, self.status_menu_var) + tuple(self.status_options))
self.status_menu.configure(takefocus=1) #Allow user to tab over option menu
self.status_menu.grid(column = 1, row = 6, sticky = "EW")
```

Comment: If you move focus to the option menu, pressing the space key should display the menu. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I hadn't tried that and it worked the first time. However, if I tab through all the widgets again, it does not work. Not sure what's going on there. Thanks though!